# Return value of recvfrom() in multicast when sender is terminated

Tags: unix, multicast, recv

In multicast what is the return value of `recvfrom()` when sender is terminated? In connection oriented the above function will return zero, But in a connectionless environment what is the return value so that receiver can be terminated normally.

Answer (score 1):

Its similar to udp: there is no such value. Not connection orientied means exactly this: ther is no connection. There is no "bookkeeping" whether there is a connection or not (on a higher level). If you want, you can make it yourself, e.g. by transmitting a certain value in your protocol.

As alternative you could just timeout, when there is no data for a certain time.